# How to actually destroy components in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, destroy, formfield

Inside an ExtJS FormPanel I dynamically add additional panels using:

```js
var sub_panel = new SubPanel({various: params});
var form_panel.items.first(); 
form_panel.insert(3, sub_panel);
```

When I load a particular subpanel and call destroy on it it still exists within the form so that if I call:

```js
form_panel.getForm().getFieldValues();
```

the fields that should have been deleted are still returning even though they have their isDestroyed property set to true.

This causes one of my checkbox's to throw the error **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"** because the dom element of the checkbox has been deleted.

Note I have tried:

- subpanel.destroy();
- subpanel.remove(true);
- subpanel.removeAll(true);

My question is either:

1. How do I make sure that getFieldValues does not include destroyed items?  OR
2. How can I actually remove the panels completely (i.e. actually destroy them)

EDIT:

I have managed to make a monkeypatch fix by having my own formIsValid method:

```
    formIsValid: function() {
        var valid = true;
        this.items.each(function(f){
            if (!f.isDestroyed) {
                if(!f.validate()){
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
        });

        return valid;
    }
```

The isDestroyed method however I think should be unnecessary so it would be better if I was able to actually destroy the component

Comment: What version of ExtJS do you use? In your code, you create a sub_panel, and do not use it? I don't understand what is the problem in your code...

Comment: Could you fix this line `var form_panel.items.first();`?

Comment: Have you tried using the latest version?

Comment: @AndreiI Sorry mistake it was supposed to be subpanel

Comment: @EvenTrimboli: Unfortunatly we are locked into using ExtJS 3.6.  An upgrade to 4.x would require a complete rewrite of the UI

Answer (score 2):

That's from the form panel that you should call `remove`, with the child panel as argument:

```
formPanel.remove(subPanel, true);
```

Comment: After changing the code to:

    form_panel.items.first().remove(sub_panel, true);

The error still occurs.  When calling validate it still throws the error:

    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined      ext-all-debug.js?1384767897:4269
    El.getValue